# Cannot get Linux to boot from usb

Tags: 12.10, boot, usb, live-usb

this is my first time trying to install Linux. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

I have tried two different Linux distos as well as two different programs to create the usb live key and have tried to install on three different computers at home and get similar results each time. I am able to get the computer to start the boot process for Linux but it always runs into an error before I get into a GUI.

I'll try my best to describe what I see: A purple ubuntu screen comes up followed by a screen with scrolling text and then what I'm presuming to be an error screen with lines of smaller text than was on the previous screen. On this screen I always see:

[    40.9760231 usb 1-8 reset high speed usb device number 4 using ehci_hcd
and...
udevd[110]: timeout: killing '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sdb' [120] which repeats itself infinitely after a while.

I have tried booting linux on two different dell inspiron 1545's as well as an old dell optiplex gx620 tower. The two aforementioned lines were common to all machines.

I've tried to troubleshoot for myself for two days and have come up with nothing. I think it's because I'm so new to this that I don't even know how to ask the right questions. I'm really excited about breaking into the linux community so this is really frustrating

Comment: It seems the problem you encounter might be with the usb key or both (Windows?) programs you've used to create a live usb. Perhaps you can try and create Ubuntu live CD from iso file, which is an easier task for poor Windows ;-) It's the fault of Windows, and not yours ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was hoping that there was something obvious that I was missing. I'll try burning a live cd

Comment: Fixed the problem! I created the live CD like was suggested and it worked like a charm! Thanks for the help Sadi!

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, it seems creating a live USB does not go as easily as live CD (especially under Windows), but you can still do it for system recovery, emergency etc. easier from Ubuntu via Startup Disk Creator.